# AirFlow SFTP upload using public key file

Tags: sftp, airflow, paramiko

I am trying to upload a file into a SFTP using a key file. I already configured the connection and I can authenticate without any problem:

```
{'key_file': '/my_folder/public_key'}
```

Also I am able to do all the process manually using Cyberduck for example. This is the function that I am calling:

```
from contextlib import closing
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook 

# Get connection details
ssh = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='my conn id')

# Upload the file into sftp
with closing(ssh.get_conn().open_sftp()) as sftp_client:
    sftp_client.put('/local_folder/my_file.xlsx', '/sftp_folder/my_file.xlsx')
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
{base_hook.py:80} INFO - Using connection to: xxxxxxx
{transport.py:1687} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client AWS_SFTP_1.0)
{transport.py:1687} INFO - Authentication (publickey) successful!
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Forbidden
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening if I am able to do the same manually?

Thank you so much!

The whole stack:

```
{transport.py:1687} INFO - Authentication (publickey) successful!
{sftp.py:131} INFO - [chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../airflow/plugins/operators/my_operator.py", line 231, in sftp_upload
    client.put(local_path, sftp_path)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 727, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 683, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, 'wb') as fr:
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 341, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 780, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 832, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 863, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Forbidden
```

Comment: From stacktrace it looks like this problem is not really related to Airflow, but the [`sftp_client` of `paramiko` library](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/sftp.html). A quick [google-search](https://www.google.com/search?q=paramiko+sftp+PermissionError%3A+%5BErrno+13%5D+Forbidden&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN752IN752&oq=paramiko+sftp+PermissionError%3A+%5BErrno+13%5D+Forbidden&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brings up quite a few discussions

Comment: @y2k-shubham just realized that the problem was the path! I was not using the full path so paramiko was returning "forbidden". Thank you so much man!

Comment: **@brenoriba** please add your solution as an answer here for reference of others

Comment: @y2k-shubham sure! I just updated! :) Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was due to invalid path in sftp folder. Cyberduck was hiding part of the path so I was including an incomplete one into my code. Paramiko was returning Forbidden because probably the path exists but this account doesn't have access to it.

Once I included the full path the code above worked pretty fine!

Thanks!

Comment: @brida How do you move a file from S3 to SFTP?